# Sql Server Express 10.0.1600 Moved to a Sql Server 2008 10.50.160

Tags: sql-server

I want to Sql Server Express 10.0.1600 Moved to a Sql Server 2008 10.50.1600.

I have only backup file as 10.0.1600 version.

It is possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine. Going up versions is not a problem, it's when you try and go the other way that you will get problems. That is as long as you're sure that all the code you have written works the same way on the newer version.